# javascript regex : extracting variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of javascript variable like this
var_111, var_222, var_132, var_122bb ...

The string after the underscore are response from a remote server, so I cannot specify them beforehand.

I want to run a for loop that would iterate through all the var_* variables. For example console.log all the variables.

I guess it can be done with regex but I really haven't learn it yet. Hope someone can help!

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. What's the actual situation?

Comment: *Have* a bunch of variables like - if so, how/where? Or *want* a bunch of variables like - if, so why? (Post context.)

Comment: Can you show us what the server response looks like?

Comment: Actually the javascript variables are the response of an remote server that I had no control of, so the structure seems kind of awkward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.match(/var_\d+/g).forEach(function(v)
{
    console.log(v); // v here is a variable such as var_111
});
```

Based on the clarification below, assuming what is actually going on is that the server is setting a bunch of global variables whose names you can't control, what you want is:

```
for (var k in window)
   if (window.hasOwnProperty(k) && k.match(/^var_\d+$/))
      console.log(k)
```

This iterates over all global variables and compares them to the regular expression to get the ones of the type var_###, and prints them out for you. You can get the values with `window[k]`. This works because all global variables are in fact properties of the `window` object.

Comment: A string such as `var str = "var_111, var_222, var_132, var_122bb";` This is what you say you are getting from the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot of your code! But unfortunately I did not know the string after the var_ before the getting the server response, hence I cannot specify var str beforehand.

Comment: @user2018232 no, str here represents the server response.

Comment: Sorry maybe I have made it clear, the server response is actually like var var_11="...."; var var_22="..."; ...